# UNIX SMTP client that supports MS Exchange proprietary (EXPS) authentication?

Tags: smtp, sendmail, exchange

I'm trying to non-interactively send emails from Solaris through an Exchange 2007 server, but the Exchange server only allows Exchange Server authentication (OWA access is also disabled).  Here's the list of enabled authentication methods returned by the server (in response to EHLO):

```
X-ANONYMOUNSTLS
AUTH
X-EXPS GSSAPI NTLM
```

(Note the absence of any specific AUTH methods.)

[X-EXPS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123786%28EXCHG.65%29.aspx) is proprietary to Exchange.

Is there a command-line UNIX (preferably Solaris) SMTP client that supports any of these authentication methods?  I've tried [smtp-cli](http://www.logix.cz/michal/devel/smtp-cli/) and Sendmail but neither seem to support Exchange authentication, nor was I able to find anything with a Web search.

If I enable TLS and basic AUTH over TLS on the server I can get smtp-cli to work (and I'm sure Sendmail will work also), but changing these settings on the server in a production environment is not an option.

Any help is appreciated.

-Ed

Comment: I'd ask your Exchange admins to add one or more mechanisms to the `AUTH` command.

Answer (score 0):

[This guy](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1237875) suggests to use [DavMail](http://davmail.sourceforge.net/) as a gateway. If this works then you could setup DavMail and then use your favorite client.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately DavMail uses OWA which is disabled on the server.